# 'ImportError' in Python extension module wrapping C library

Tags: python, c, compilation, cython

*(**UPDATE 3** contains the questions I'd like to get answers to. **UPDATE 2** refers to corrections I did trying to understand and fix this issue)*

I'm trying to get a Python extension module to wrap a C library (in this case, it is only an example described in the book [Python Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449340377) (3er edition.) The problem is that I'm encountering the classic error

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initsample)
```

when I'm trying to import the module.

The book itself has the following comment:

> For all of the recipes that follow, assume that the preceding code is found in a file named
>   sample.c, that definitions are found in a file named sample.h and that it has been com‐
>   piled into a library libsample that can be linked to other C code. The exact details of
>   compilation and linking vary from system to system, but that is not the primary focus.
>   It is assumed that if you’re working with C code, you’ve already figured that out.

And I think I'm getting that wrong. This is what I'm doing: First of all, I have the following files:

```
➜  Sample  ls
csample.pxd  sample.c  sample.h  sample.pyx  setup.py
```

The content of the files is according to [this github repository](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/tree/master/src/15/wrapping_existing_c_code_with_cython) containing the files described in the book. Assuming everything is copied correctly. I then compile `sample.c`

```
➜  Sample  gcc -c -fPIC -I/path/to/python2.7 sample.c
```

This creates `sample.o` and I proceed to create a shared library:

```
➜  Sample  gcc -shared sample.o -o libsample.so
```

It creates a `libsample.so` and finally run the `setup.py` file:

```
➜  Sample  python setup.py build_ext --inplace 
running build_ext
skipping 'sample.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'sample' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/path/to/include/python2.7 -c sample.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sample.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sample.o -L. -L/path/to/lib -lsample -lpython2.7 -o /path/to/sample.so
```

However, I obtain the same error. What am I missing?

This is my `setup.py` (eventually, I copied a part to clean previous build):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import sys
import os
import shutil

# clean previous build
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if (name.startswith("sample") and not(name.endswith(".pyx") or name.endswith(".pxd") or name.endswith(".h"))):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        if (name == "build"):
            shutil.rmtree(name)

ext_modules = [
Extension('sample',
    ['sample.pyx'],
    libraries=['sample'],
    library_dirs=['.'])]

setup(
    name = 'Sample extension module',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I was wondering if it is normal that after running

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

the file `sample.c` gets replaced with a cythonized version. 
I assume that running `setup.py` is using `cython sample.c`, but I'm asking this because yesterday I was mistakenly compiling the cythonized version `sample.c` (after removing `libsample.so`, `sample.o`, `sample.so` that were created in a previous run) and after updating `sample.pyx`, I got this error:

```
>>> import sample
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./sample.so: undefined symbol: divide
```

After this, I restored `sample.c` to its original [content](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/15/sample.c), removed all remaining files from previous builds (including temporal files) and crucially, I had to change `sample.pyx` in some way (e.g. adding a blank line.)

I noticed I have to do this to avoid the

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initsample)
```

error. Then I proceeded as usual:

```
➜ Sample  gcc -c -fPIC -I/path/to/python2.7 sample.c
➜  Sample  gcc -shared sample.o -o libsample.so
➜  Sample  python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning sample.pyx to sample.c
warning: sample.pyx:27:42: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
building 'sample' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/path/to/include/python2.7 -c sample.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sample.o

gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sample.o -L. -L/path/to/lib -lsample -lpython2.7 -o /path/to/Sample/sample.so
➜  Sample  python
>>> import sample
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libsample.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This time I get `cythoning sample.pyx to sample.c` in the output above and a new error. However, `libsample.so` is in the `Sample` directory. What could be the issue here?

**UPDATE 3:**

I finally was able to import this module successfully but the last error

```
ImportError: libsample.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

implied that I needed to set the current directory in the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. However, I did it in a crude way:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/Sample
```

What is the correct way to do this? Maybe using some parameter in `setup.py`? Regarding the several issues I found, I'd like to get an answer as to why all of this happened:

1. `sample.c` gets replaced when running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` Is this okay?
2. Do I need to restore `sample.c` every time I'm doing this procedure?
3. Do I need to change `sample.pyx` in order to get a correct output (instead of `skipping 'sample.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)` with a misleading output)
4. What is the correct way to solve `ImportError: libsample.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`?

A possible [solution](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/cython-users/1353z5mts4/how-do-i-list-a-dependent-shared-library-in-the-extension-setup-py) to 4. is to add in `setup.py`:

```
runtime_library_dirs=['./'],
```

However, this requires `libsample.so` to be located in the same directory as `setup.py`.

Comment: Please show us your `setup.py` file.  Also, please verify that Cython works on your `sample.pyx` file (using `cython sample.pyx`).

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. `cython sample.pyx` works but it replaces the file sample.c that is in the same directory. I will update my question with the contents of `setup.py`

Comment: And? Dos your module indeed contain the mentionned function `initsample()`? If not, read again the error message ("`ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initsample)`")...

Comment: @glglgl No, there is no `initsample` function. The error adds the part `init` to whatever your module is called.

Comment: @RobertSmith So you have the reason: as you might know or not, the Python module system requires exactly this function to be present in every module: a `PyMODINIT_FUNC initNAME(void)`, where `NAME` is the name of your module. And if this function is not present, you get exactly this error. Do proper module init under the proper name and the error is gone.

Comment: Thanks. Should this declaration be added to `sample.c` using `#include <Python.h>`? Shouldn't this be included by Cython?

Comment: What if you delete all generated files, including the `build` directory, `sample.c` and `sample.h`, and run `setup.py build_ext`?

Comment: @gl: Cython is responsible for providing this function; it is not OP's mistake.

Comment: @JanneKarila When I do that, it throws an error saying that it needs `sample.pxd`. I tried to run it again including `sample.pxd`  but says it needs `sample.h`. I included files until it throws an error presumably asking for a shared library.